# Display prices with and without VAT on WooCommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display prices with and without VAT on the cart page. but when I call the price variable gives me zero value.

I used this snippet code:

```php
function sv_change_product_price_cart( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    global $product;
    $price = $product->price ;
    $price_excl_tax = $price - round($price * ( 20 / 100 ), 2);
    $price_excl_tax = number_format($price_excl_tax, 2, ",", ".");
    $price = number_format($price, 2, ",", ".");

    $display_price = ' <span class="amount" >';
    $display_price .= '<span class=" eptax "><span class="nprice">£ '.  $price_excl_tax.'</span><small class="woocommerce-price-suffix" style="color:black" > ex VAT</p></small> ';
    $display_price .= '<span class=" ptax " ></small><span class="nprice">£ '. $price .'</span><small class="woocommerce-price-suffix" style="color:black"> inc VAT </p></small>';
    $display_price .= '</span>';
 
    return $display_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'sv_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
```

And it gives me this:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the price(s) on the cart page, in that specific column you can use the `woocommerce_cart_item_price` filter hook.

Functions used:

- [wc_get_price_excluding_tax()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_price_excluding_tax/)
- [wc_get_price_including_tax()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_price_including_tax/)

---

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_item_price( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // Get the product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Price without VAT
        $price_excl_tax = (float) wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );
        
        // Price with VAT
        $price_incl_tax = (float) wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );
        
        // Edit price html
        $price_html = wc_price( $price_excl_tax ) . '<span class="my-class">&nbsp;' . __( 'ex VAT', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span><br>';
        $price_html .= wc_price( $price_incl_tax ) . '<span class="my-class">&nbsp;' . __( 'inc VAT', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
    }

    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
```